# Is it unsafe to use rand to generate a uuid?

Tags: ruby

For creating a non-sequential, unique user id, I know I can use:

```
SecureRandom.uuid
```

The problem is it's a little bit slow, and we're obsessed with the responsiveness of our API.  I am trying to determine if I can replace the id generation with something like this:

```
rand(36**10).to_s(36)
```

which is faster, and generates a seemingly random, usually 10 digit alpha-numeric.  Is this safe?  Will `rand` truly generate an id more or less uniformly distributed across the `36^10 ~ 3.5e15` large space of possibilities?  Or in practice will the distribution be non-uniform and thus more likely to produce collisions?

Any other gotchas I should know about or alternatives I should consider?

Comment: Have you actually determined that (a) you have a performance bottleneck, and (b) your DB isn't already capable of producing a UUID?

Comment: (a) See my reply to @spickermann.  (b) i don't know the answer that, i'm using redis right now but plan to switch to postgres, or possibly something else, in production.

Comment: (a) See my reply to your reply, (b) Postgres has UUIDs; personally I don't see much value in not using UUIDs from SecureRandom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit off topic, since you asked about safety of the `random` method, but anyway:

You mentioned that you need the random numbers to generate user_ids with a low probability of collision. I think it is not worth it to discuss performance issues:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'securerandom'

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bmbm(15) do |x|
  x.report("random:")   { n.times do; rand(36**10).to_s(36); end }
  x.report("uuid:")     { n.times do; SecureRandom.uuid; end }
  x.report("hex:")      { n.times do; SecureRandom.hex; end }
end

# Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
# random:           0.070000   0.010000   0.080000 (  0.062774)
# uuid:             0.800000   0.000000   0.800000 (  0.802512)
# hex:              0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.361002)
# ------------------------------------------ total: 1.240000sec
# 
#                       user     system      total        real
# random:           0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.062458)
# uuid:             0.820000   0.000000   0.820000 (  0.820784)
# hex:              0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.341963)
```

You are right `SecureRandom.uuid` is 13 times slower than just `random`. But you are still able to generate ~1000 uuids per millisecond. That is negligible to the time it takes to store such an uuid in the database. IMO an update to a database takes at least 2-3ms.

Furthermore the readablity of `SecureRandom.uuid` is much better than your `rand(36**10).to_s(36)`.

Comment: Wow weird when I run it in IRB there is one second pause to  generate a single one

Comment: @Jonah That *is* weird; you might need to provide additional details. I can't reproduce that behavior on any system.

Comment: Okay, so it appears only to have the 1-2 second delay on the first call.  I fire up irb, then do `require 'securerandom'` and then `SecureRandom.uuid` -- 1-2 second pause, then result.  Then if I call `SecureRandom.uuid` additional times, it returns instantly.

Comment: @Jonah Can't reproduce that either, but ok.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could move the slow process into the background:

- Keep a pool of uuids in a fast datastore (e.g. Redis).
- When the API requires a uuid, get the oldest uuid and remove it from the pool.
- Have a background job that monitors the pool and adds a new uuid whenever the size drops below the limit.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a good thought, and it would solve my problem.  However, if the `rand` code were in fact reasonably safe, I would prefer that solution as it's much simpler.

Comment: True, it's more complicated, but I'd argue it's nowhere near as hard as proving that a random number generator is secure.

Comment: Yes, but do keep in mind I'm not using it to encrypt credit cards or anything like that.  I just need to create unique user ids with a very low probability of collision and reasonably difficult to guess.

Comment: It is ridiculous to think that a call to an external service like Redis is faster than a simple `SecureRandom.uuid`. `Benchmark.measure { 100000.times { SecureRandom.uuid } }.total` return under 0.78sec on my old MacBook. That mean ~1000 uuid per millisecond.

Comment: Well I've never used SecureRandom, so I have no idea how fast it is. OP seemed to think it was slow. I wasn't claiming that it would be faster, only showing a technique for making the API more responsive. One more tool for the toolbox.